# Who intercepts my touchEvent?

Tags: android, touch, viewgroup, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a expandable RecyclerView where you can expand/collapse each item. Each item also contains a Seekbar. If a items starts out as expanded the seekbar works great, but if the items starts out in it's collapsed state and is expanded I run into problems.

The problem is that when you touch the seekbar the (seekbar) view recieves a ACTION_DOWN event followed by an ACTION_CANCEL.

According to the documentation this means that some view higher up in the viewgroup has intercepted the touch event: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

However, I have been unable to locate the view which intercepts my events (and why). I also have no idea how to do it.

any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: its probably RecyclerView that eats your events

Comment: posting some code would help - how do you generate your views? what does your layout manager do?